# Denoising a chart (array of points)

Tags: c#, .net

I wanted to ask what do you think would be the best way to denoise an array of coordinate points.

I've got something like on the bottom drawing and need to convert it into what's on the top drawing.

[image]

Thanks :)

Comment: What charting component are you using - MS Chart control? Also, what is the chart type?

Comment: Probably some kind of line fit.  Though in your case it looks like you'll need different fits for different x ranges.

Comment: I've got an array of Points in C#

Comment: @RogerTravis Array of Points, yes. How are you displaying them? What chart control/chart type?

Comment: I just draw them on an empty bitmap using SetPixel(pointX,pointY,Color)

Comment: What is on the top is too clean to be expected from what is on the bottom.

Comment: The good ol' batman/pacman graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Median filter

A typical way of doing signal noise removal is a [median filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter).

If you have a noisy signal f(x), you can get a denoised signal g(x) by the following:

g(x) = median<sub>z in R(x)</sub>(f(z))

where R(x) = [x-w/2, x+w/2] and w is some window width.

## Example

Wikipedia has [a concrete example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter#Worked_1D_example).

Here's an example of denoising using a median filter. The first image is the source, the second image is the noisy version, the third image is the denoised version, and the fourth image is the difference between the source and the denoised versions. Notice that most of the error is near boundaries, whereas error in regions without sudden jumps is very low.

[image]

---

For a broader look at the topic, look at [Noise reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_reduction).